# Confusion regarding skeletal animation in the vertex shader

Tags: java, vertex-shader

I see that there are some fairly similar questions, but those are mostly regarding performance. I would be very grateful if someone could take the time to explain as to how I could implement what I currently have into the vertex shader(For animation, as the title states).

I have a simple .FBX file reader which extracts the following:

Vertex coordinates (X, Y, Z);

Vertex indices;

Normal coordinates (X, Y, Z);

As far as bones go:

Bone names
Indices of the vertices attached to the bones;

The weight of each of the vertices;

A 4x4 matrix array of the bone. (Not sure how this is laid out, please explain! Wouldn't the matrix only hold the position of 1 end?)

---

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you may be missing a few things. Most notably, the bone hierarchy.

The way it typically works, is you have a root node, whose transformations propagate down to the next level of "bones", whose transformations propagate, and so on until you reach the "leaf" bones, or bones with no children. This transformation chain is done using matrix multiplication.

There are a few ways to then transform the vertices. It's sometimes done with with an "influence" that is decided on beforehand and is usually loaded from a 3d application such as 3dsmax.

There's another way of doing this which is simple and straightforward. You simply calculate the distance from the vertex to the bone node. The influence of the bone's transformation is directly related to this distance.

The 4x4 matrix you speak of holds much more than just position. It holds rotational data as well. It has the potential to hold scaling data as well but this typically isn't used in skinning/bone applications.

Getting the orchestra to play together nicely requires a thorough understanding of matrix math/coordinate systems. I'd grab a book on the subject of 3D math for game programming. Any book worth its weight will have an entire section devoted to this topic.

Comment: Thanks, but I suppose I didn't specify on my knowledge of matrices. I know that it holds rotation and well as scaling data, but what I meant to ask, doesn't it only hold one end of the bone? As in the joint? Regardless, I suppose this is what I looking for, answer accepted.

Comment: @Braindrool: That is correct, it only holds one end of the bone and that is typically the "local origin" of the bone.